# JQuery slider not showing properly

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

We are using JQuery (jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js and jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css) for our Android app. In a screen we need a slider to the user. The code of the div is as follows:

```
<div id="jetlag_optionround">
    <span class="option_span">Round Trip:</span>
    <div class="option_select">
        <select name="flip-mini" id="flip-mini" class="ui-slider" data-role="slider">
            <option value="off">Off</option>
            <option  value="on" selected="selected">On</option>
        </select>
    </div> 
</div>
```

But while sliding sometimes its showing the images like the attached image.[image]

What could be the reason behind this? Have anybody faced this kind of problem before?

Comment: Which jquery slider plugin you are using?

Comment: @Andru jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js and jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css

Comment: that's jquery plugin...not the slider plugin i guess!

Comment: So, I just tested out your code with a base jQuery (1.x latest) and 1.3.2 jquery.mobile here: http://jsfiddle.net/h4LsX/. Appears to be working fine. My guess (and you can edit your post to show it) is that you're doing something with the CSS in your own stylesheets that is mucking with it. Can't tell without more details.

Comment: @JasCav Its working fine in browsers and even on iPhone apps but not in Android apps. Please note: Its happening some times(30% - 40%).

Comment: @Mayank you are right. Its JQuery plugin.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar - Can you post up your own JSFiddle that replicates the problem? This will help us debug. Otherwise, your question (probably) can't be answered in its current form.